# MS Excel VBA - Match/Index trying to pull in dates to add to a total date duration

Tags: vba, excel

```
For DurcurrRowIn = 14 To .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
  DurcurrRowIn = DurcurrRowIn + 1
  Set DurlookFor = wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(currRowIn, "C")   ' value to find
  Set Durlookforin = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & DurcurrRowIn & ":C500")
  On Error Resume Next
  DurStart = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wb.ActiveSheet.Range("F:F"), WorksheetFunction.Match(DurlookFor, Durlookforin, 0))
  DurEnd = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wb.ActiveSheet.Range("G:G"), WorksheetFunction.Match(DurlookFor, Durlookforin, 0))
  Dur1 = DurEnd - DurStart
  Dur = Dur + Dur1
Next
```

Looking to perform an index/match to grab an employees id on the current row and look for it further down the column not including the row I'm currently in. Once it finds the same employee id, grab the start/end dates and determine their durations, then add that figure to the total duration number (dur). Currently not grabbing the dates, though it did work when my "Durlookforin" was just the whole column C, which doesn't really help. Will post my dimensions below.

```
Dim DurcurrRowIn As Long
Dim DurcurrColIn As Long
Dim DurcurrRowOut As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Dur As Long
Dim Dur1 As Long
Dim DurEnd As String
Dim DurStart As String
Dim DurlookFor As Range, Durlookforin As Range
```

Test File Here

[image: Test File Here]

Comment: I've been playing around with the dimensions, trying DurStart/DurEnd as Dates

Comment: Are they only listed twice and does it have to be a formula? Also, it would be great to see some sample data.

Comment: They may be on the list multiple times, once the end row is reached and the code moves to the next part it will do either one process or another depanding on If Dur >365

Comment: Can you post an example of your data and what you expect the results to be?

Comment: What are you going to do with the duration once you get it?

Comment: Leads to an IF statement, if duration is over 365 then do one process, else, do another process. Adding test excel file now

Comment: Basically I'm adding deductions into a payroll file, but if the employee has worked multiple times throughout this process I need to add up the total duration for this employee and if the duration is >365 then some items are not going to be added to the payroll file..I have that part covered it's just this index/match. I want to move to the next line as to not count the duration I started on or that was previously counted.

Comment: It was properly pulling the dates and calculating the Dur when 'Set Durlookforin = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C:C") however it obviously would keep adding the same dates and not keep moving to the next row.

Comment: Well I don't understand your data setup well enough because you haven't posted it. I can guess that you have a name and a date, and further down, there's the same name and a different date? Use `Range.Find` instead of `.Index` and you can use `.FindNext` to look for other values below.

Comment: I'll try that..sorry wasn't able to insert an excel file (or I just don't know how) I did insert a link to a screenshot of the test workbook at the end of my post. See "Test File Here"

Comment: How might I use find/find next with my current code?

Answer (score 0):

Using Employee ID's as keys to a Dictionary makes it easy to add up the Durations.

Most of this code generates a report but this is all you need to get the Durations by Employee ID's

```
For x = 14 To lastRow
    dicIDs(.Cells(x, "C").Value) = dicIDs(.Cells(x, "C").Value) + .Cells(x, "G").Value - .Cells(x, "F").Value
Next
```

### Sample Data

[image]

### Result

### [image]

```
Sub GetDurations()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const SOURCE_SHEETNAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim dicIDs As Object
    Set dicIDs = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")

    With Worksheets(SOURCE_SHEETNAME)
        lastRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 14 To lastRow
            dicIDs(.Cells(x, "C").Value) = dicIDs(.Cells(x, "C").Value) + .Cells(x, "G").Value - .Cells(x, "F").Value
        Next

        Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A14:D" & lastRow).Copy Range("A2")
    End With

    Columns("D").ClearContents
    Range("A1:D1") = Array("LastName", "FirstName", "Employee ID", "Duration")

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A1:C" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastRow
        Cells(x, "D").Value = dicIDs(Cells(x, "C").Value)
    Next

    Columns.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you are not familiar with using a Scripting Dictionary then this is a must see [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&t=242s&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=43)

Comment: I will definitely have to look more into this method as it may save me a lot of time. Is there any way to use dictionaries without the reporting side of it, is that would you explained in the first part?

Comment: @Ace16150s I put the report in so that you can see how to lookup the values.  `dicIDs("TestID1")` would return the value that is stored in the dictionary for the key "TestID1".

Comment: Awesome, and when it grabs the next employee to do the same search process it will overwrite the first employees information?

Comment: @Ace16150s you should watch the video I have linked in my answer.  Dictionaries store data in key value pairs.  In my answer the keys are the Employee ID's and values are the values associated with each key.  You can literally store up to 2 billion key/value pairs in a Dictionary.